# Special Characters Showing up in Python Dict built form AWS and being passed to js through django view

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, dictionary

I'm calling some information about my infrastructure and attempting to build a dictionary that I can convert to json as objects and pass it to javascript to display.

I have tried using json.dumps and simplejson.dumps to the dictionary.

I'm assuming that its because the dict has nested dicts within it.

Here is the structure of the data

python print out of data as its passed to the webpage through django.

```
    {'SecurityGroup:eiddo-slave-elb': {'rules': {'ingress': {'to_port': '0000', 
'ingress_grants': "{'sg-000000': {'cidr': 'None', 'group_id': 'sg-00000', 
'grant_name': 'None'}}", 'from_port': '7001', 'protocol': 'tcp', 'groups': ''}, 
'egress': {'to_port': '0001', 'egress_grants': "{'sg-000000': {'cidr': 'None', 
'group_id': 'sg-00000', 'grant_name': 'None'}}", 'from_port': '0000', 'protocol': 'tcp', 'groups': ''}}, 'id': 'SecurityGroup:eiddo-slave-elb', 'tags': '{}'}}
```

web console output of the data. The syntax error is from jquery because it can't parse the data to accomplish the loop. As you can see there are a lot of special characters in the data passed. I've even tried encoding the strings of the dict to UTF-8

```
    Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: {&#39;SecurityGroup:eiddo-slave-elb&#39;: {&#39;rules&#39;: {&#39;ingress&#39;: {&#39;to_port&#39;: 
&#39;7001&#39;, &#39;ingress_grants&#39;: &quot;{&#39;sg-000000000&#39;: 
{&#39;cidr&#39;: &#39;None&#39;, &#39;group_id&#39;: &#39;sg-54b09d31&#39;, 
&#39;grant_name&#39;: &#39;None&#39;}}&quot;, &#39;from_port&#39;: 
&#39;7001&#39;, &#39;protocol&#39;: &#39;tcp&#39;, &#39;groups&#39;: &#39;&#39;}, 
&#39;egress&#39;: {&#39;to_port&#39;: &#39;0000&#39;, &#39;egress_grants&#39;: 
&quot;{&#39;sg-00000000&#39;: {&#39;cidr&#39;: &#39;None&#39;,
 &#39;group_id&#39;: &#39;sg-00000000&#39;, &#39;grant_name&#39;: 
&#39;None&#39;}}&quot;, &#39;from_port&#39;: &#39;7001&#39;, &#39;protocol&#39;: 
&#39;tcp&#39;, &#39;groups&#39;: &#39;&#39;}}, &#39;id&#39;: 
&#39;SecurityGroup:eiddo-slave-elb&#39;, &#39;tags&#39;: &#39;{}&#39;}, 
&#39;SecurityGroup:asgard&#39;: {&#39;rules&#39;: {&#39;ingress&#39;: 
{&#39;to_port&#39;: &#39;None&#39;, &#39
```

JS
        var security_groups = "{{security_groups}}";

```
    $(security_groups).each(function( index ) {
      console.log(security_groups[index]);
    });
```

Python Code

```
    def getSG():
        conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-west-2',aws_access_key_id='', aws_secret_access_key='')
        rs = conn.get_all_security_groups()
        rule_list = {}
        ig_grants = {}
        eg_grants = {}
        sg_dict = {}
        flag = True

        for item in rs:
            rules = item.rules
            for rule in item.rules:
                for grant in rule.grants:
                    ig_grants[str(grant)] = {'cidr': str(grant.cidr_ip).strip(), 
                                             'group_id': str(grant.group_id).strip(), 
                                             'grant_name': str(grant.name).strip()}

                rule_list['ingress']= {'from_port': str(rule.from_port).strip(), 
                                       'to_port': str(rule.to_port).strip(), 
                                       'groups': str(rule.groups).strip(), 
                                       'protocol': str(rule.ip_protocol).strip(),
                                       'ingress_grants': str(ig_grants).strip()
                                       }
                ig_grants = {}

            for rule in item.rules:
                for grant in rule.grants:
                    eg_grants[str(grant)] = {'cidr': str(grant.cidr_ip).strip(), 
                                             'group_id': str(grant.group_id).strip(), 
                                             'grant_name': str(grant.name).strip()}

                rule_list['egress']= {'from_port': str(rule.from_port).strip(), 
                                      'to_port': str(rule.to_port).strip(), 
                                      'groups': str(rule.groups).strip(), 
                                      'protocol': str(rule.ip_protocol).strip(), 
                                      'egress_grants': str(eg_grants).strip()
                                      }
                eg_grants = {}
            sg_dict[str(item)] = {'id':str(item).strip(), 'rules':rule_list, 'tags':str(item.tags).strip()}
            rule_list = {}

        return sg_dict

    def index(request):
        conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-west-2',aws_access_key_id='', aws_secret_access_key='')
        #instances = get_ec2_instances(conn)
        rs = conn.get_all_security_groups()
        security_groups = getSG()
        print security_groups

        template = loader.get_template('index.html')
        context = RequestContext(request, {'security_groups': security_groups,})
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

My goal here is to pass it to js as a json string and convert it into a json object.

I know that I'm not including JSON.parse in my js because I want to get the string to look correct without the special chars. because when i do

```
    JSON.parse(security_groups);
```

I get the following error:

`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{{ security_groups }}` in your template outputs an HTML-escaped representation of a Python dictionary. That's not something Javascript can parse properly.

Instead, use JSON (a.k.a. JavaScript Object Notation), which JS will know how to load.

---

To do so,

In your view code, change

```
context = RequestContext(request, {'security_groups': security_groups,})
```

to:

```
context = RequestContext(request, {'security_groups': json.dumps(security_groups),})
```

(you'll need to add `import json` at the top of your file)

And in the JS code, change:

```
var security_groups = "{{security_groups}}";
```

to:

```
var security_groups = JSON.parse("{{ security_groups|escapejs }}");
```

Or simply (but not recommended):

```
var security_groups = {{ security_groups }};
```

Comment: thanks that really helped, but I don't understand the difference, is it just ehe escapejs i was missing? or do i have to dump to json in the request context?

Comment: You have to do both things. Dumping it as JSON ensures it can be loaded back in JS. Escape JS ensures JS can actually parse the string (because JSON contains '"' signs, which would break otherwise).